# Preselect category filter in LIferay Documents and Media Portlet

Tags: select, liferay, portlet, documents

I want to set a specific category as selected when creating new document in Documents and media portlet. I only have the category Id passed as parameter in the url. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I cannot give an answer, but I'd suggest you to check [how to override Struts action](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions). I believe the action you would have to check is `EditFileEntryAction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using parameter `assetCategoryIds`. In url this parameter might look like `_20_assetCategoryIds_22902` and `_20_` is a portlet namespace (Documents and Media) and `_22902` is your vocabulary id.

Example url:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_p_id=20&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=2&_20_repositoryId=20182&_20_fileEntryTypeId=0&_20_cmd=add&_20_struts_action=%2Fdocument_library%2Fedit_file_entry&_20_folderId=0&_20_assetCategoryIds_22902=22904
```